# Enable emailing from MAMP

Tags: php, email, mamp

I'm trying to get email sending enabled in MAMP(note: not pro) so I can test things like: contact forms; registration forms; etc.

I did find this "quick-tip" on how to do it [Enable mail on localhost on MAMP](http://wardkennes.be/2013/03/14/enable-mail-on-localhost-on-mamp/), which I tried.

So, this is what I've got; `sendmail_path = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f mymail@mymailhost.com"` in my php.ini file. I've tested a few different types of forms which send emails... but still nothing. :(

Should I be editing something else in edition or am I on the wrong track? Thanks!

Comment: From my experience using any of the PHP functions, e.g. `mail()`, work just fine without additional configuration. Even libraries such as `PHPMailer` and `Swift Mailer` work out of the box. Could you elaborate a little on how you want to send the e-mails?

Comment: @NikolasGrottendieck: I wasn't doing anything beside the code that I shared above... I guess that's why it wasn't working. :P

When it comes to how I want to send them; I just want to send them to something like a gmail or yahoo mail host (or something similar) to be able to test my code. Do you have examples of how to do this with the things you listed/which method would you suggest as the best?

Comment: Well … my examples would be directly integrated into the PHP application you are developing. I.e. a user submits a form with the necessary information (target address, title and content of the message) and you'd simply call `mail(…)` (see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)) from the PHP page processing the form. The equivalent operations apply to the libraries I named. Or do you simply want to redirect the users to their own mail client and proper target address and information set?